Access event data during Journey
Im curently developing a journey that generates some objects to serve as logs to Salesforce using the the Object Activity.
I need data like the Journeys name and when that specific client entered it. How can I access this data?


To clarify, I wanted information that is not available in the Contact and Journey data on the right, like the current Journey name. Is it possible?

Hi gabriel you have to click on journey data, then you can choose your fields from the entry event 
regards

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
